# GoogleMaps API: kml on top of polygon

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

How can I render my polygon behind the kml layer?

I have a kml layer imported into my Google Maps canvas. Also, I have implemented a polygon, which is drawn on the canvas whenever you click *Draw*.

The issue is that when you click *Draw* the polygon is drawn on top of the kml markers. Thus, I cannot click any marker and visualize their respective names. In other words, I would like to be able to know which markers are included inside the drawn polygon, and for that I would need to click the marker and see its corresponding name.

I believe the solution lies in using panes. I am aware of panes and the order in which they are arranged, but I don't know how to implement a solution using them.

To follow, I'm including my code almost exactly as I have it, so you can see what I am talking about and test it yourself. The only difference is that I'm not including my key for GoogleMaps, so where you see **API_KEY**, replace for your own key. Thanks in advance.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjL8y9ov/2/)

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="GoogleMapTEST.js"></script>

<style>
    html{ 
    height:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    }
    body{
    height:60%;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS',  'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
    font-size:10pt;
    background-color: LightGray;
    line-height:1.6em;
    }
    #map-canvas {
    width:80%;
    height:500px;
    margin-left: auto;  
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-top: 50px;   
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .col2{
    border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    width: 39%;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    }
</style>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>                                                       

<div>
    <form>
        <fieldset class="col2">
            Search radius (km): <br><br>
            <input type="text" id="DrawTxt" value="30">
            <input type="button" id="DrawBtn" value="Draw">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var map;
var overlays_array = [];                                                            

function initialize()                                                               
{
    var MyLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51,-114);                         
    var mapOptions = {                                                              
        center: MyLatLng,
        zoom: 10
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);    

    $("#DrawBtn").click( function(){                                                
        ClearOverlays();                                                            
        var radius = $("#DrawTxt").val();                                           
        var circle = DrawCircle(map.getCenter(), radius);                            
        AddOverlay(circle);                                                         
    });

    var CP_url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2KR4Lz3foYEd04za21sMXZYaEE'      
    var CP_options = {
        preserveViewport: true,                                                                     
        map: map                                                                                    
    };
    var CP_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(CP_url, CP_options);                                    
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);        

function DrawCircle(center, radius)
{
    var nodes = 72;

    var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween( center, new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()+0.1, center.lng()) )/100;
    var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween( center, new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(), center.lng()+0.1) )/100;

    var points = [];
    var step = parseInt(360/nodes)||10;

    for(var i=0; i<=360; i+=step)
    {
        var pint = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + (radius/latConv * Math.cos(i * Math.PI/180)), center.lng() + (radius/lngConv * Math.sin(i * Math.PI/180)));
        points.push(pint);
    }
    points.push(points[0]); 

    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: "#00A2FF",                               
        strokeOpacity: 0,                                     
        strokeWeight: 0,                                      
        fillColor: "#80D0FF",                                 
        fillOpacity: 0.3                                      
    });

    return poly;                                              
}

function AddOverlay(overlay)                                  
{
    if(overlay)
    {
        overlay.setMap(map);                                  
        overlays_array.push(overlay);                         
    }
}

function ClearOverlays()                                      
{
    while(overlays_array[0])                                  
    {
        overlays_array.pop().setMap(null);                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option (if your kml is not too complex) would be to render the KML as normal Google Maps Javascript API objects using a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/), then you can control their ordering with respect to the circle.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_circle&layer.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var MyLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51,-114);                         
  var mapOptions = {                                                              
    center: MyLatLng,
    zoom: 10
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);    
  geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
              map: map,
              infoWindow: infowindow,
              singleInfoWindow: true,
              markerOptions: {optimized: false}
          });
 geoXml.parse("http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/CPs_Calgary.kml");
// ...
```

[example with 494 markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_circle&layer.html?filename=koolid_surfinsky_com_kml3.xml)

[example with 839 markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_circle&layer.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/nzhistory_net_nzmap_locations_kml.xml)

Comment: I have run into that parser, but my original KML is composed of about 900 points or markers. Thank you.

Comment: Last I checked, with v3 900 points will not cause performance issues.  Not sure what your target environment is though.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have just tried that and it didn't work. Most likely I'm doing something wrong. I added the script that references the source and then added the rest of your code below `map = new google.maps......`. The line where it is parsed, I substituted with my own url: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2KR4Lz3foYEd04za21sMXZYaEE

Comment: geoxml3 uses the XmlHttpRequest object for access to the KML, so is subject to that object's [same domain security restriction](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/11/09/fixing-ajax-xmlhttprequest-considered-harmful.html).  Did you host the KML on the same server as the web page?

Comment: no, I have the KML in GoogleDrive and for the web page I use Webmatrix.

Comment: using geoxml3, would there be a way of having the KML always show the info windows of all markers?

Comment: Yes, set the following option to the parser: `singleInfoWindow: false`. Then write code to either "click" on each marker after creation or open its infowindow.

Comment: Interesting, I will be trying to host the page and file on the same server next week probably. Anyway, would you know how to do what I am trying just using panes or something else?